# How to rephrase this notice setence?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, usage

I'm developing an app, and there's a feature there to show QRCode and other people can scan it. But the QRCode can be expired, and if it is, I want to let the scanning people know that they should ask again from the people/contact that send them the QRCode, that they should refresh the QRCode and send them again.

I plan to write it like this. But the wording sounds convoluted. Can you help me rephrase this sentence to be more natural sounding?

> Sorry, the QRCode doesn't exist or has expired. Please ask again for the refreshed QRCode from the person you received the QRCode from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Sorry, that QRCode doesn't exist or has expired. Please try again.

Simply saying "please try again" is more straightforward and more understanding.

Comment: Ah, I see. Because the previous sentence has already said "expired", then following by "try again" will automatically direct the user to re-ask again. Thanks!